# How to automatically reverse the direction of a motor without human intervention?

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, physics

I am working on this project where I have an arm at rest want a brushless DC motor (BLDC) to automatically reverse:[image] (I've added an image and text above for a visual reference) Given that I am taking High School Physics, and am not in any way good at engineering, how can I accomplish this as simply and as inexpensively as possible? Thank you in advance for all of your help!

Comment: Do you realize you cannot just hook up a BLDC motor to a power supply? You need an electronic controller for it so the controller should be the first place you look for any behaviour you wish to do with the motor.

Comment: So would you recommend an ESC? Do you know if any of them can automatically reverse the direction of the motor, as I need?

Comment: Airplane ESCs do not reverse. Truck/car ESCs do. None auto-reverse because that is not needed and dangerous on airplanes and trucks.  For auto reverse you will need to add a microcontroller to control the ESC and a limit switch so the MCU knows when the ends are reached. I recommend picaxe if you are low on money and experience.

Comment: perhaps the cheapest solution is a mechanical solution where the motor turns at a constant speed without reversing ... think `windshield wipers`

Comment: What is the arm? If it is not very lightweight you will probably want to ramp speed up and ramp back down rather than trying to stop it instantly. Look into automatic gate openers. Also, you will probably want some kind of reduction gear or use a leadscrew unless it is OK to have a very large motor.

Comment: @jsotola's window wiper solution is worth investigating. A rear window wiper is self contained and the self park feature could be a bonus.

Comment: @Transistor How exactly do rear window wipers work?

Comment: @jbethel11, shame on you for asking ... do some investigating on the internet ... do search for images of wiper mechanism

Comment: @jsotola I don't think there is any shame in me asking. However, before your response, I did some research and saw how it works. Still, a bit confused on how to connect the dots, though.

Comment: perhaps not shame, but you should not feel comfortable asking how a windshield wiper mechanism works ... there are numerous examples on the internet and this site is not about mechanical engineering ... too many people ask a question here first, before trying to answer their question themselves

Comment: think about the motion of your femur when you pedal your bike

Answer (score 1):

Most hobby brushless ESCs can be reflashed with an open source firmware, which could be trivially modified to implement the auto reversing behavior.

If an MCU based brushless motor drive can operate in both directions or only one is effectively a *software* function, so to an extent it does not really matter if the original firmware was "airplane" or "car" style.

That said your application might be a better fit for a `stepper motor` which is a sort of brushless motor optimized for open loop use in discrete increments of movement.  If you want to use a traditional brushless motor, you'd probably need one with hall sensors (and compatible driver) and some sort of mechanical reduction such as a timing belt or even 3d printed herringbone gears.  Speaking of 3d printers, the drive electronics for those are typically Arduino-based open source multi-channel stepper motor controllers, albeit ones targeted at relatively small motors.

The *mechanical* engineering of your project is going to require as much more more attention as the electrical, but is not strictly speaking on topic *here*.

Sometimes it's best to go looking through the world and find some existing machine that does something like what you need, and either see how it works, or even adapt it for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have been looking at various machines that function similarly, like railroad crossings, automatic garage door openers, and windshield wipers. However, none of them actually show the motor used; or if they do I cannot seem to simplify it to a point where I understand how to use it. Railroad crossings are the closest machines to what I actually need, but that is the hardest to find details on what motors are used.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the motor is going through a reduction gear of some kind, or you would need a stepper motor. The ESCs for model vehicles sense the voltage generated by the motor windings (back EMF(a fancy term for voltage in the electrical trade)) to determine commutation time & direction for the coils. The motor only has 3 wires (no Hall sensors). If your ESC does not have a direction input, just reverse any 2 of the motor leads with a reversing switch. If it does, you can get a CMOS flip flop ic with set & reset i/ps, like a CD4013B, connect it to the direction i/p, ground the clock & D i/ps, & other unused i/ps, & use the limit switches (with pulldown resistors of about 100K) to switch the flip flop. Put about a 100uF capacitor across the supply pins of the flip flop, & maybe a 100Ω resistor before it as a decoupler to prevent noise from the motor flipping it. Or you can just reverse the motor leads as above.[image]